# Яке значення має слово "легiт"?

Tags: значення-слів

Михайло Коцюбинський писав: “Сонце грає промінням, весняний легіт жене по небесній блакиті як пух легенькі білі хмаринки…”. Яке значення має слово "легiт"? схоже на легкий шепiт, але я не впевнена. Пiдскажiть, будь ласка.
Дякую за увагу.

Comment: Наступного разу, будь ласка, додайте до запитання Ваші спроби самостійно знайти відповідь. За посиланням можете, прочитати як правильно ставити питання https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Згідно із Словником української мови online (1-8 томи)

> ***[ЛЕГІТ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47035&page=1485)*** готу, чоловічий рід, поет. *Легкий приємний вітерець. Сонце грає промінням, весняний легіт жене по небесній блакиті як пух
>   легенькі білі хмаринки* (М. Коцюбинський); // переносне значення.
>   *Шум, гомін і т. ін., що нагадують віяння легкого вітерцю. Безжурні заклики фуркотіли у леготі дерев* (К. Гриневичева)